# How to increase import processing speed in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I am using the django import-export module to import xlsx files. When the number of rows is less (say about 2000) the file is getting imported quickly. But this is not the case when I upload a file about 50k rows. It is showing some error like "Transaction support timed out." How can I upload a large xlsx file through django import - export?

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to share the code that handles the import?

Comment: I am not using any code for importing . I am using the inbuilt django feature "from import _export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin". And then from the django admin page, I am using the import button to upload the excel files.